# How to export and import React on another App

Tags: reactjs, npm, bundle, rollupjs, pack

I've two Apps App1 and App2, both of them are created using create-react-app. Where as App1 is created as a package using rollup and then npm link/npm link package name.

While importing on App2 I'm getting Attempted import error: 'App2' doesn't not contain a default export (imported as Header)

On App1 I've this in App.js

```
import Header from './Header'    

function App () {
return (
   <div className="App">
    <Header text='hello' />
   </div>
);
}

 export default App
```

I've created this App1 as a package, now How to access Header component from App2

```
import Header from 'App1'
function App () {
return (
  <div className="App">
   <Header text='new text' />
 </div>
 );
}
export default App
```

Comment: You need to export header from `App1` like this `export { Header }` then import in `App2` like this `import { Header } from 'app1'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export Header in App1 like this.

```
...
export { Header };
export default App;
```

And, in App2, you can import the Header component from App1 this way:

```
import { Header } from 'App1';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header text="new text" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know, If the issue still persist.

Comment: Thanks Maulik for your quick turn around. Issue still exist. More details on the app. App1 was converted as a package using rollup and then npm link/npm link package name. That's what I did. Now the issue says Attempted  import error: 'Header' is not exported from 'App1'

Comment: I haven't used rollup, I have worked with the npm publish. But, I will get back to you - once i will try with the code.